# Google Analytics API returning only 'google / cpc' as medium?

Tags: python, google-analytics

I have been trying to fetch data from Google Analytics using its python API but its not returning data for all the entries in the field in `ga:sourceMedium` as `df['ga:sourceMedium'].unique()` returns: `array(['google / cpc'], dtype=object)` but there are several others sources and mediums present on Google Analytics. I am using correct parameters as far as I know but here are they in case I am not:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'GA_credentials.json'
VIEW_ID = '56495678'
SHEET_ID = ''

DIMENSIONS = ['ga:date','ga:sourceMedium','ga:campaign']
METRICS = ['ga:impressions', 'ga:adClicks','ga:adCost']

startDate = '2018-01-01'
endDate = 'today'
pageToken = '2000'
pageSize = '100000'
```

Any help/hint is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'ga:impressions', 'ga:adClicks', 'ga:adCost'` are metrics of Google Ads, they cannot be associated with a medium such as `referral` or `organic` so you are returned those of Google Ads, precisely `cpc`.

Comment: But there are facebook.com and others through which campaigns run. They do show up on web. Should I remove these?

Comment: For facebook and others provider did you import the cost data (clicks, cost, impressions) into Google Analytics?

Comment: Clicks and impressions are not automatically acquired by Google Analytics, they must be imported.

Comment: It turned out I needed to import. Thanks! Once imported they are shown as others